# Changing a Facebook group setting from "secret" to "closed"

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

How can I change the privacy setting of a Facebook group (500+ members) from secret to closed?

I can't see any option to do so in Edit Group Settings.

Answer (score 4):

As of January 2016: 
  It seems that at some point recently, the Facebook article quoted by AlvaroFG was edited ("about a month ago") and now reports that the cut-off number is 5,000. If you still are under 5,000 members you should be able to change.

https://www.facebook.com/help/286027304749263

Comment: OK well I have confirmed...   There is a group that I am a member of (not an admin) with about 3,200 members that wanted to change.  I alerted the admin, and she has now successfully changed the group from secret to closed.

Answer (score 1):

You might if you are still under 5k members, as per [Facebook rules](https://www.facebook.com/help/412300192139228) after a group gets above a certain size (5000 users), you can only increase its privacy level.

> Groups with 5,000 members or more:
>
> - The privacy of the group can only be changed to a more restrictive setting (ex:Public to Closed, or Closed to Secret). We do this to protect members of these groups from having their posts shared with audiences they didn't intend.
> - Once the privacy is changed to a more restrictive setting, all admins have 24 hours to change it back.

(Thanks [Michael Bray](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/36993/changing-a-facebook-group-setting-from-secret-to-closed/98474#comment75601_52168))

Comment: As of some recent date ("about a month ago" according to the article you quoted) the cut-off number is now 5,000.  I have confirmed in a FB group that I'm a member of (I alerted the admin) and she changed the group from secret to closed..  so the 250 number is old information.